# Adding time duration from an array in Perl

Tags: regex, arrays, perl, time, grep

So I'm trying to add some given times such as:

```
my @arr = ("stuff (00:04)", "more stuff (02:59)", "extra stuff (00:00)");
```

and the () are formatted as (HH:MM) HH= hours, MM = minutes. so my idea is to extract the time duration in the () using this code:

```
my @new_arr = grep (/\b\(\d:\d\)\b/, @arr);
foreach (@new_arr){
    print "$_";
}
```

but my regex isn't working.

Also I have no idea how to add them up.

so any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modified code:

```
my @arr = ("stuff (00:04)", "more stuff (02:59)", "extra stuff (00:00)");
my @new_arr = map { /\((\d+:\d+)\)/ ; $1 } @arr;
foreach (@new_arr){
    print "$_\n";
}
```

Explanation:

Your code has 2 problems:

1. Your regular expression to match the time duration (`/\b\(\d:\d\)\b/`) is incorrect. For example, `\d` could only match one single digit, while in your case there're two on both sides of `:`;
2. `grep` evaluates each element of your list, and return the elements for which the expression returns true. So even your regular expression is correct, it will return the whole element of array, not the matched part. You should use `map` instead, which return the result of expression, so you could construct an expression which gives the matched part.

Comment: So I used your method and implemented it on a larger code: `use warnings;
use strict;
my @arr = ("stuff (3+06:13)", "more stuff (02:59)", "extra stuff (00:00)");
my @new_arr = map { /\((\d+:\d+)\)/ ; $1 } @arr;
my @x = map {/\((\d+\++)/ ; $1 } @arr;

my ( $sum, $hrs, $mins );
$sum = 0;
for my $t (@new_arr) {

 my ( $h, $m ) = split m/:/, $t;

 my $hm = $h * 3600;
 my $tm = $m * 60;

 $sum = $sum + $hm + $tm;
}

$mins = sprintf( "%02d", ( $sum % 3600 ) / 60 );
$hrs  = int( $sum / 3600 );

print "$hrs:$mins\n";` but I did get

Comment: `Use of uninitialized value $t in split at directory/test.pl line 13.
Use of uninitialized value $h in multiplication (*) at directory/test.pl line 15.
Use of uninitialized value $m in multiplication (*) at directory/test.pl line 16.
2:59`

Comment: @Amture101 That's because the first element of `@array` turns out to be `stuff(3+06:13)` and doesn't match the previous regular expression any more.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to recommend storing your information as a hash instead of an array:

```
my %times = ( 
    "stuff" => "00:04",
    "more stuff" => "02:59", 
    "extra stuff" => "00:00",
);
```

Now, you can fetch your times for the stuff:

```
my $stuff_var = "stuff";
print "It took $stuff $time{$stuff} to run\n";
```

If your data is in an array, you can parse it using the `m//` regular expression:

```
my %times;
for my $time ( @arr ) {
    $time =~ /(.*)\s+(.+?)/;   # Parentheses mark stuff and time
    my $stuff = $1;
    my $time  = $2;
    $time{$stuff} = $time;
}
```

Now you have a hash `$time` with your timestamps. If you want to separate out hours and minutes, you'd use the same technics. I would make a hash of hashes:

```
my %times;
for my $item ( @arr ) {
    $itme =~ /(.*)\s+(.+?)/;   # Parentheses mark stuff and time
    my $stuff = $1;
    my $time  = $2;
    $time{$stuff}->{TIME} = $time;
    $time =~ /(.*):(.*)/;
    $time{$stuff}->{HOUR} = $1;
    $time{$stuff}->{MINUTE} = $2;
}
```

Now `$time{$stuff}->{TIME}` will be `(HH:MM)`, while `$time{$stuff}->{HOUR}` will be the hours, and `$time{$stuff}->{MINUTES}` will be the minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `map()` to traverse each element of the array an extract each time doing grouping in regular expression:

```
@new_arr = map { m/\((\d{2}:\d{2})\)/ && $1 } @arr
```

It yields:

```
00:04 
02:59 
00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an additional info. grep function is used only to filter the array. Hence using map function is the right option. map function is used for transforming lists element-wise: given a list and a code block, map builds a new list (or hash) with elements derived from the corresponding elements of the original.